# How to get the selected value on a Dropdown of <div> <p> using JQuery by click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown Month that its filled dynamically depending on the year selected input.

[image]

When the user click on the Month Dropdown, this show a list of months. 
**how do I get the selected month value by the user using JQuery? Assuming that the dropdown list is filled dynamically.**

This function gets called when the user click on the displayed list of months

```
$("#month").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).children("div p").val(); // return undefined
    console.log("month: " + value);
});
```

HTLM Dropdown

```
<div id="month">
    <span class="input">März</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user click on the Dropdown Month, the `UpdateMonths()` functions gets called and filled the list dynamically

```
$("#month span").click(function(event) {

    $("#month div").html(UpdateMonths());


    event.stopPropagation();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) { // only open downdown when not disabled
        Dropdown($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    } else Dropdown(); // hide all dropdown menues
});

function Dropdown (element) {

    $("#month div").hide(); // hide all dropdowns
    if (element) $("#"+element+" div").toggle(); // show dropdown of specified element
}
```

This is how I fill the list

```
function UpdateMonths(){
var temp = "";
    if (parseInt(Get.Year()) <= 2012){
        for (var i = 0; i < Get.Months.length; i++) {
            var monthsChain = "<p>"+Get.Months[i]+"</p>";
            temp += monthsChain;
        };
    }else{
        temp = "<p>Januar</p><p>Februar</p><p>März<p></p><p>April</p><p>Mai</p><p>Juni</p><p>Juli</p>"; 
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Is the selected value in the span or in the p?

Comment: Unrelated, but class names cannot start with '.' in your third line. This should be `<div class="dropdown">`.

Comment: Wait... are you wanting to fill `.input` with the text of the last `<p>` that the user clicked on? Your question is getting harder to understand...

Comment: You aren't really clear on what you are after or you don't show necessary structure. If you hook the `#month` `click` event, there is no way you can identify correct month. Do you mean you click the `span`, or even `p`?

Comment: @Puuskis I meant the user click `<p>`

Comment: @RamiroTomato I added answer that should do exactly that. Please take a look at it and respond if there's something that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your selected value is in the `<span>` not the `<p>`, so it should be:

```
var value = $(this).children("span.input").text();
```

**Edit: you can do it like this:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#month', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('p')) {
        var value = $(e.target).text();
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi MrCode :), this returns the last value of the array

Comment: How are you determining that an item is selected, some sort of class or data attribute?

Comment: I actually don't, I just implementing the click event. But if I do `$(#month div p").click(function() {` the `var value = $(this).text(); ` gives me the right selected month. The problem with that was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473829/click-event-not-called-by-dropdown-in-javascript-using-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var value = $(this).find("div p").text();
```

Or more specific:

```
var value = $(this).find("div.dropdown p").text();
```

Comment: Yap, I also tried that but I get a list of all the values of a list. e.g.: month: JanuarFebruarMärzAprilMaiJuniJuli

Comment: The second one, doesn't return any value

Comment: As @MrCode sugested, the value you are looking for is in span, not in p. You can use `$(this).find(".input").text();`

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is used to get the value of form fields. If you want the text content of a generic HTML element (such as `<span>` or `<p>`, you need to use `.text()`:

```
$("#month").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('.input').text();
    console.log("month: " + value);
});
```

Make sure you remove the period (.) from the HTML class of your dropdown, too - classes must start with a letter, not numbers or punctuation.

Comment: I already tried but this returns the last value of the array no matter where I clicked. I also removed the period from the HTML class.

Comment: I really don't have a clue what you want to happen! Your question keeps getting more confusing as you edit it. Can you break it down and tell us exactly what you want to happen when someone interacts with your site?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to get the month selected from the list of `p` elements.

HTML (structure similiar to question)

```
<div id="month">
    <span class="input"></span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p>January</p><p>February</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="year">
    <span class="input"></span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p>2013</p><p>2014</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery, delegate event needed because `<p>` elements are generated dynamically.

```
$("#month, #year").on('click', '.dropdown p', function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    console.log("month: " + value);
});
```

How to set month value to span (inside the scope above)

```
$(this).parent().siblings('span').text(value);
```

And jsfiddle to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/2nuhw/4/

Comment: I already tried, but this just work if the list <p>January</p><p>February</p>etc.. are predefine at the beginning on the html structure as static list.

Comment: @RamiroTomato My bad, you need delegate event handler. I updated the jQuery part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use val() for input fields. use text() to get the text fields. Usually

and  having text.

try like this:

```
var value = $(this).children("div p").text();
```

or

```
var value = $(this).children("div p").html();
```

using html() you can get any type of value that belongs to the span or p tag.

Comment: `var value = $(this).children("div p").html();` return undefined and var value = $(this).children("div p").text(); nothing